# Mat-select selected value is undefined

Tags: html, angular, typescript, forms, angular-material

I have multiselect list and when I select the option I can't get the value, not from the event, not from the property, everything that I tried `-ngModel/value/ formControl` is undefined. Why?

```
  <div class="flex" style="width:35%;float:right;margin-top:10px;flex-direction:column">

            <form [formGroup]="filterSearchForm"> 

            <mat-form-field style="width:70%">
                <mat-select [formControlName]="'customField'" [(ngModel)]="selectedUserType"  [multiple]="true" placeholder="בחר" (selectionChange)="filterByCustomFields($event)">

                    <mat-option *ngFor="let custom of filteredRows" #matSelect  (onSelectionChange)="filterByCustomFields($event,matSelect)" [value]="custom.value">
                        {{custom.fieldHebKey}}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
            </form>


        </div>
```

Comment: Impossible to say without a [mre], but you're mashing too many things together: you are using reactive forms AND template driven forms with two-way binding AND two instances of output binding.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen without thr ngmodel what can be the reason?

Comment: Without a [mre], it's just guesswork.

Comment: I guess formcontrolname does not go well with ngmodel on the same element (mixing template driven and reactive forms).